# Как применить библиотеки requests, что бы передать данных данные на omnidesk?

Tags: python, telegram, requests

Я хочу что бы сообщение пользователя в telegram передавалась в omnidesk через URL. Подскажите, как мне это сделать?

Comment: @insolor этот не тот сайт. Я имел введу про этот omnidesk (https://omnidesk.ru/api/introduction#intro)

Comment: Отлично, значит изучаете эту документацию, по ней выполняете нужные запросы

Comment: @insolor Прежде чем задать вопрос, я это и сделал. Но я все равно не знаю как мне отправить сообщение из телеграмма в omni

Comment: Точно так же как не из телеграма. Если используете requests, то используете соответствующий тип запроса: requests.get, requests.post, и т.д.

Comment: https://curlconverter.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как написали в комментарии можно использовать этот [сайт](https://curlconverter.com/), что бы преобразовать curl в код на python.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/872401)

Comment: @NowhereMan Дак так и сделано

Comment: @NowhereMan это ссылка сервис, её работу в ответе никак не повторишь